# Generic "running averager"

Tags: c++, template

The basic "running averager" is familiar, both in embedded as well as real-time applications such as games, eg for fps. This algorithm is implemented in many microcontrollers (notably the PIC series) for analog input averaging. This is a software replacement.

Usage: We feed sample values using `operator()` and the current "running average" is returned on each call. `max_samples` determines the "time-constant" of the averaging. The higher, the smoother the the output. We don't need to store the samples, as we can calculate the new `sum` by subtracting the previous `avg` and adding the `new_value`.

In order not to have a distorted `avg` for (at least) the first `max_samples` samples, we count up to `max_samples` with `sample_count` and use that for the denominator. While we have not yet reached `max_samples` we don't subtract the `avg` when adding `new_value`.

The algorithm is very simple. Choosing the right types is not quite so easy. Especially when done generically.

Concerns:

- Signedness
- Narrowing
- Other unwanted implicit conversions
- Overflow --- not covered in the demo code in main
- Really small types like `unsigned char` -- untested
- the `static_cast` which is required to silence some Type combinations, eg `Value/Sum=float` and `Count=int`, but might be hiding other problems
- Use of `operator()`. Originally I had a `sample(Value new_value)` member function

Compiled with

`clang++-13 -std=c++20 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wextra-semi  -Werror`

and that is error free. Tried to provide sensible defaults for the `Sum` and `Count` types, but allowed them to be customised.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename Value, typename Sum = Value,
          typename Count = std::conditional_t<std::is_signed_v<Value>, int, unsigned>>
requires std::floating_point<Value> || std::integral<Value>
struct averager {
    Sum   sum{};
    Value avg{};

    Count       sample_count = 0;
    const Count max_samples;

    explicit averager(Count max_samples_) : max_samples(max_samples_) {}

    Value operator()(Value new_value) {
        if (sample_count != max_samples) {
            sum += new_value;
            ++sample_count;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "new_value(" << typeid(new_value).name() << ") - avg("
                      << typeid(avg).name() << ") = " << new_value - avg << "("
                      << typeid(new_value - avg).name() << ") :";

            sum += new_value - avg; // correct, and well defined, even with unsigned types
        }
        // count's signedness has been matched to sum and avg
        // must accept that, eg float has fewer sf than int, on many architectures
        avg = sum / static_cast<Sum>(sample_count);
        return avg;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        std::cerr << "\naverager<int>(3)\n";
        auto a = averager<int>(3);
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 5; ++i) std::cerr << "10 => " << a(10) << "\n";
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 10; ++i) std::cerr << a(5) << "\n";
    }
    {
        std::cerr << "\naverager<long>(3)\n";
        auto a = averager<long>(3);
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 5; ++i) std::cerr << "10 => " << a(10) << "\n";
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 10; ++i) std::cerr << a(5) << "\n";
    }
    {
        std::cerr << "\naverager<unsigned>(3)\n";
        auto a = averager<unsigned>(3);
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 5; ++i) std::cerr << "10 => " << a(10) << "\n";
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 10; ++i) std::cerr << a(5) << "\n";
    }
    {
        std::cerr << "\naverager<std::size_t>(3)\n";
        auto a = averager<std::size_t>(3);
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 5; ++i) std::cerr << "10 => " << a(10) << "\n";
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 10; ++i) std::cerr << a(5) << "\n";
    }
    {
        std::cerr << "\naverager<float>(3)\n";
        auto a = averager<float>(3);
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 5; ++i) std::cerr << "0.1F => " << a(0.1F) << "\n";
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 10; ++i) std::cerr << a(0.05F) << "\n";
    }
    {
        std::cerr << "\naverager<double, double, std::size_t>(3)\n";
        auto a = averager<double, double, std::size_t>(3);
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 5; ++i) std::cerr << "0.1 => " << a(0.1) << "\n";
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 10; ++i) std::cerr << a(0.05) << "\n";
    }
    {
        std::cerr << "\naverager<int>(long double)\n";
        auto a = averager<long double>(3);
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 5; ++i) std::cerr << "0.1L => " << a(0.1L) << "\n";
        for (auto i = 0U; i != 10; ++i) std::cerr << a(0.05) << "\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think I have worked out what 'max_samples ' is for ,but please explain it in the question

Comment: @pm100
Ok, I have done a general description of the algorithm including that point.

Answer (score 1):

There's a real risk that `sum` could overflow if it's one of the integer types and `max_samples` is too large.  I think the algorithm is incorrect after `max_samples` is reached - some good unit tests would help ensure it works.  (The test program is a good start towards that, but requires manual inspection of output).

There's a way to compute a running mean without overflow and with minimal round-off error, by not storing the sum - just count and mean.  From those, the total can be inferred, and we update the mean by linear interpolation between current mean and the added value (moving mean 1/count of the way towards the value - and updating count of course).  For that, I would store `mean` as `std::common_type_t<Value, double>`.

Comment: For working code using this principle, see my review request: [Compute mean and variance, incrementally](/q/198124/75307).

Comment: The question was deleted.  I didn't name / describe this well enough. The intention is NOT to produce an accurate arithmetic mean on a running basis. But to produce a "smoothed value" which follows a "noisy signal" without using storage. The algorithm is correct for that. It follows exponential decay type maths. I will repost the question with better names / description. I would like to re-delete this one, which was already deleted before any answers came. Can you re-delete it please. As it is, it's just confusing.

Comment: No response? 
I studied your stats bag. It's nice, but it's not the same. RollingStatsBag comes the closest to what I intend here, but it's different because it uses storage (a `std::deque`). My code should run on uC where a large "array" of any sort is not feasible. It should also work with integer types only, including tiny, single byte types. In fact, the algorithm I (believe correctly) implemented is implemented in the PIC series of 8-bit micros in hardware. It's not an arithmetic mean, but it does a very good job of smoothing a noisy value with exponential decay / time constant maths.

Comment: Yes, I meant to point to just part of my question - the other parts (including variance calculation and windowed functions) aren't relevant to this question.  I was just addressing the numeric part.

Comment: Could it be made less confusing by re-writing the description and title?  I was disappointed to see the question disappear under me when my answer was almost complete - that's why it got reopened.  I'm not sure whether it's a valuable question or not, now - please come over to [the 2nd Monitor](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595) if you're able to put a case for deleting for mods to consider.  (And sorry I'm in lots of meetings today; will try to look in from time to time).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were writing an answer, when I deleted it. I don't care that much if it gets deleted, that's up to the moderators. But i won't engage with this version any more. I have found some much better names, and a much better way of explaining the algorithm.

Comment: It seems perhaps not that many people are aware of this algorithm - it matters in embedded, and it's also useful as a high speed "damper on noisy stats" in other settings (Frame rate displays, or wifi signal strength would be a classic applications). No allocations, so very lightweight and fast. So I will post the new code with full unit tests across a wide range of types in a new code review.